# Не работает сравнение переменной со считаной строкой из файла с read

Tags: bash, shell

Имеется текстовый файл. Хотим найти строку, содержащую конкретное число.
Открываем файл, записываем строку файла в переменную LINE, сравниваем ее со значением переменной, содержащей интересующее нас число.

```
temp='2420'
while read LINE
do
    if [[ $LINE = $temp ]];
    then
        echo "True"
    else
        echo "False" 
    fi
done < ShowMesh.unv
```

Получаем `False`, хотя в текстовом файле гарантированно имеется строка `2420`.

Comment: *гарантированно имеется строка `2420`* — это вторая и последняя строка, причём в конце неё нет символа `\n`? тогда всё верно делает ваш скрипт: второй строки для него «не существует».

Comment: Нет, это не вторая и не последняя строка. \n имеется. И я не очень понимаю, почему второй строки не существует.

Comment: 1. каждая строка (включая последнюю) должна заканчиваться символом `\n`. 2. строки надёжнее будет помещать при подстановке в двойные кавычки. 3. [mcve]

Comment: @Kola, [УМВР](https://paste.pound-python.org/show/xVMZqS9gxR8dLkthrVkG/), так что пример входных данных, ожидаемого результата и действительного результата в студию...

Comment: Никак не могу понять, как тут прикрепить файл или скрин. 
В файле имеется строка 2420, имеющая в начале несколько пробелов. записываю temp='2420', сравниваю строку с temp, получаю false.
Надеюсь, что я понятно выражаюсь, если нет - заранее прошу прощения, нет опыта в использовании.